# COM port numbers change after reboot. Can they be persistent?

Tags: windows, serial-port, port

I have devices with USB ports. I'm running a script which needs port numbers to be hard-coded in it.

The problem is that after my devices reboot, the numbers of COM ports change, and then my script can no longer communicate with the devices.

How can I make my COM port numers persistent, even after reboot? (windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a virtual comm port. Hardware comm ports should not randomly be reassigned ports from the OS unless you have something really wacky going on with your configuration. So, if you really are using a virtual comm, specifically FTDI, you should try adding a REG_BINARY key with a value of 01 to the key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\UsbFlags\IgnoreHWSerNumXXXXXXXX`

where XXXXXXXX is the vid pid of your virtual comm usb device. This is explained on http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?ignorehardwareserialnumber.htm

Note, the part about setting this flag BEFORE installing the driver. Be sure to uninstall, set this flag, then reinstall. If you are not using a different vendor you should check their documentation for similar feature.